# Binary number and measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider I express all the number between $[0,1]$ into binary number. Define the set $X:=\{x\in[0,1]|(0.1x_{1}1x_{2}1x_{3}...),x_{i}\in\{0,1\}\}$. Now I believe this set is uncountable, totally disconnected. But what about the measure of $X$? Can it be measure zero?

My intuition tell me that if this is true, then it's complement $[0,1]$\ $X=\{x\in[0,1]|(0.x_{1}x_{2}...),x_{i}\in\{0,1\},x_{2j}=0$ for some $j\in\mathbb{N}\}$ should have full measure, but it expression is almost identical to $X$, and also it is uncountable, totally disconnected, how can I tell which one has measure zero(if any on them are)?

**Edit**: Thanks to the comment, I notice the complement is wrong. Now the question become how do I tell the measure of $X$

Comment: The completement is wrong, it would one $0.x_1x_2\cdots$ with at least one i such that $x_{2i} = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the measure, note that we may write $X = X_0 \cup X_1$ where $X_0 = \{\frac{2 + x}{4} : x \in X\}$ and $X_1 = \{\frac{3 + x}{4} : x \in X\}$ (since $X_0$ accounts for binary sequences beginning with zero and $X_1$ accounts for binary sequences beginning with $1$). Now we see that $\mu(X_0) = \mu(X_1) = \frac{\mu(X)}{4}$ by translation invariance and scaling. And $0 \leq \mu(X) \leq \mu(X_0) + \mu(X_1) = \frac{\mu(X)}{2}$. Therefore, $\mu(X) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

To show that the measure is zero, note express $X$ as $\bigcap_n X_n$, where the measure of $X_n$ is at most $2^{-n}$ and use the continuity of the measure.